# Emacs Searching

Tags: search, emacs

I have a convoluted search request. Lets say that I am searching for an URI pattern. I do know the scheme and the authority. Lets say **http://mycompany.com.**

After this URI pattern, ideally most of the URI in my search domain have two path variable. 
**/Context/Resource**. Although it could have more. But it will always have a context.

I would like to find the distinct set of first path variable. I do not mind about the  second and subsequent path variable.So if I have this.Lets use a qname is myc.

```
    myc:/context1/resource1
    myc:/context1/resource2
    myc:/context2/resource1
    myc:/context3/resource1
    myc:/context4/resource8
    myc:/context1/resource12
```

I will have to get context1..4. Thank You for your time.

Comment: Need clarification: Do you mean you want to search from the current position (with its associated context) for the first location of a different context?  e.g. If you were at the top of the example (context is `context1`), you want to get to the 3rd line (`context2`), and a subsequent search would find `context3`, and another `context4`, and another `context1`?   Or something else?

Comment: @Trey, I am not sure if I Completely understand your question. But I think we are in the same  page...

Comment: Lets say that I have a regular expression mentioning get all the string with starts with the uri-pattern, I could use M-x list-matching-lines. This will give me the list of search result. I was wondering if I could do further processing on the search result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,

```
(require 'cl)

(remove-duplicates
 (loop while (re-search-forward "myc:/\\(.*?\\)/" nil t)
       collect (match-string-no-properties 1))
 :test #'string=)
```

Comment: I was hoping is there could be something inbuild. Yes, this is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs supports regex searches which are normally bound to `C-M-s`.
The [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) has a nice section about regular expressions in Emacs.

There is also `M-x regexp-builder` to help you build the search string with real-time feedback.

Comment: Is the problem just searching? I have the search result in the form of line items, but I would like to further process the list to extract distinct items.